# Deadlocks in MYSQL: How to find out why a lock cannot be acquired?

Tags: mysql, deadlock

We have the following situation which yields to a deadlock as shown by the SHOW INNODB STATUS result:

- Transaction1 is trying to update mytable where id = 5 and waits for a row lock record of type **X**
- Transaction2 is trying to update mytable where id = 5 holds a row lock record of type **S** and waits for a row lock record of type **X**

None of the two transaction actually hold the right record, so we can't really understand why this would yield to a deadlock, unless there is a third transaction who owns that lock and is deadlocked as well. How can this issue be further investigated and can be somehow be related to triggers?

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-07-28 08:27:08 0x7f1a08537700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2183, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 5, locked 5
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 47, OS thread handle 139750051079936, query id 1481 172.24.0.1 myuser updating
update `mytable` set `status` = 'OK' where `mytable`.`id` = 5
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 37 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `mydb`.`mytable` trx id 2183 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000885; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 2c0000018b0110; asc ,      ;;
 3: len 30; hex 66643164396162382d663462642d343237652d626461362d316430626634; asc fd1d9ab8-f4bd-427e-bda6-1d0bf4; (total 36 bytes);
 4: len 4; hex 5b5c28d7; asc [\( ;;
 5: len 4; hex 5b5c28dc; asc [\( ;;
 6: len 6; hex 80000186a000; asc       ;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;
 8: len 3; hex 455552; asc EUR;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 10: len 17; hex 52454144595f464f525f414456414e4345; asc OK;;
 11: SQL NULL;
 12: len 3; hex 8fc55a; asc   Z;;
 13: len 3; hex 8fc55a; asc   Z;;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: len 15; hex 30303141307965644562686c466966; asc 001A0yedEbhlFif;;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2187, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 5, locked 5
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 50, OS thread handle OK, query id 1482 172.24.0.1 myuser updating
update `mytable` set `status` = 'OK' where `mytable`.`id` = 5
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 37 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `mydb`.`mytable` trx id 2187 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000885; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 2c0000018b0110; asc ,      ;;
 3: len 30; hex 66643164396162382d663462642d343237652d626461362d316430626634; asc fd1d9ab8-f4bd-427e-bda6-1d0bf4; (total 36 bytes);
 4: len 4; hex 5b5c28d7; asc [\( ;;
 5: len 4; hex 5b5c28dc; asc [\( ;;
 6: len 6; hex 80000186a000; asc       ;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;
 8: len 3; hex 455552; asc EUR;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 10: len 17; hex 52454144595f464f525f414456414e4345; asc OK;;
 11: SQL NULL;
 12: len 3; hex 8fc55a; asc   Z;;
 13: len 3; hex 8fc55a; asc   Z;;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: len 15; hex 30303141307965644562686c466966; asc 001A0yedEbhlFif;;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 37 page no 3 n bits 72 index PRIMARY of table `mydb`.`mytable` trx id 2187 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 18; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000000885; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 2c0000018b0110; asc ,      ;;
 3: len 30; hex 66643164396162382d663462642d343237652d626461362d316430626634; asc fd1d9ab8-f4bd-427e-bda6-1d0bf4; (total 36 bytes);
 4: len 4; hex 5b5c28d7; asc [\( ;;
 5: len 4; hex 5b5c28dc; asc [\( ;;
 6: len 6; hex 80000186a000; asc       ;;
 7: len 4; hex 80000005; asc     ;;
 8: len 3; hex 455552; asc EUR;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 10: len 17; hex 52454144595f464f525f414456414e4345; asc OK;;
 11: SQL NULL;
 12: len 3; hex 8fc55a; asc   Z;;
 13: len 3; hex 8fc55a; asc   Z;;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: len 15; hex 30303141307965644562686c466966; asc 001A0yedEbhlFif;;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd transaction does hold a shared (`S`) lock, which prevents the 1st transaction to obtain an exclusive (`X`) lock.

But mysql registered that the 1st transaction wants to have an exclusive lock, which goes into the queue.

Then the 2nd transaction wants to escalate the lock to exclusive, which it cannot do because the 1st transaction already registered its intention for an exclusive lock.

This is the textbook case for a deadlock in mysql, see section [14.5.5.1 An InnoDB Deadlock Example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlock-example.html) in mysql manual

Comment: Thanks, but what does stop the 2nd transaction to acquire the X lock and to proceed and conclude itself?

Comment: The design of mysql. The above is the documented behaviour of mysql.

Comment: Understood, then, why does the second query which is identical to the first one acquire that S lock?

Comment: It is the transaction and not the query that obtained the shared lock. You must investigate your code preceeding the update. You may want to consider using select ... for update to obtain an exlusive lock instead of a shared one, or change the statement setting the shared lock not to set any locks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way to log all the transaction ? I have been looking around on the net but didn't find a simple way to get all the queries for that transaction

Comment: You need to turn on query logging within mysql or you have to log all queries within your application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176931/discussion-between-edmondo1984-and-shadow).

Comment: Use the "general" log, not the "binlog", since you need to see `SELECTs`, too.